# Do (any) trackballs allow to retrieve the rotation around the Z axis?

Tags: 3d, mouse, hardware, device-driver, trackball

The question might be a bit weird, especially because trackballs are not so common these days.
But i have a kensington expert mouse here, and since i'm creating a graphic tool, i was wondering whether there is any way to retrieve from the driver or some other kind of API the yaw, or rotation of the ball around the axis perpendicular to the table.
Alternately, and that would be best, a rotation matrix, or the rotation axis and the angle of rotation.

I'm afraid the answer might be no, but in such case, is there any other trackball model that allows this?

Answer (score 1):

There is one device that can do that it is the 3Dconnexion SpaceNavigator look at it, but its more like a joystick knob then a trackbal http://www.3dconnexion.eu/products/what-is-a-3d-mouse.html

Comment: Right, it looks more like a joystick. I'd really like to find a proper ball, though. Something like an expert mouse, that is large enough to spin it through its z axis